# Unable to download application, Application could not be Installed

Tags: xcode, ipad

I've seen this issue posted several times but my exact situation doesn't seem to apply.  Hopefully someone can help!

I'm deploying a app to the iPad.  I develop it using a Development Provisioning Profile and can deploy it without issue to the device assigned.  All well and good.

So I'm ready to distribute it.  We are using Enterprise Ad-Hoc distribution, and are part of the Apple Enterprise Developer program.  I created a Distribution Profile for the application, downloaded the profile and loaded it into Xcode, got the appropriate certificate so it is cleanly signed.  I built the distribution explicitly using the Distribution Profile for the application.  However, when I try to install, we get the infamous "Unable to load application, application could not be installed at this time."  The device console has the following errors:

```
Aug  9 10:50:43 unknown installd[12695] <Error>: entitlement 'get-task-allow' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Aug  9 10:50:43 unknown installd[12695] <Error>: entitlement 'get-task-allow' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Aug  9 10:50:43 unknown installd[12695] <Error>: 2ffba000 verify_signer_identity: Could not copy validate signature: -402620394
Aug  9 10:50:43 unknown installd[12695] <Error>: 2ffba000 preflight_application_install: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.xU9kDU/foo_extracted/Payload/APP.app
Aug  9 10:50:43 unknown com.apple.itunesstored[12694] <Notice>: MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
Aug  9 10:50:43 unknown installd[12695] <Error>: 2ffba000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Aug  9 10:50:43 unknown installd[12695] <Error>: 2ffba000 handle_install: API failed
Aug  9 10:50:43 unknown installd[12695] <Error>: 2ffba000 send_message: failed to send mach message of 71 bytes: 10000003
Aug  9 10:50:43 unknown installd[12695] <Error>: 2ffba000 send_error: Could not send error response to client
Aug  9 10:50:54 unknown lockdownd[26] <Notice>: 00381000 lockssl_handshake: SSLHandshake returned -9806
Aug  9 10:50:54 unknown lockdownd[26] <Notice>: 00381000 handle_start_session: Could not enable SSL. Closing connection.
Aug  9 10:50:54 unknown notification_proxy[12630] <Error>: Could not receive size of message: 0 Invalid argument
Aug  9 10:50:54 unknown notification_proxy[12630] <Error>: Could not receive message
Aug  9 10:50:54 unknown notification_proxy[12626] <Error>: Could not receive size of message: 0 Invalid argument
Aug  9 10:50:54 unknown notification_proxy[12626] <Error>: Could not receive message
Aug  9 10:51:03 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: lockbot[12696] Builtin profile: gputoolsd (sandbox)
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?  It seems to imply that the provisioning profile is incorrect, but I am definitely using the Distribution Profile that includes the application.  It also hints at an SSL problem; the site hosting the distributable is not SSL-enabled, but that didn't seem to need to be a requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, when you upgrade the iOS developer program subcription, you need to create new distribution certificate (and that certificate should be created by Team Agent).
See this article:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1